# Unable to get `include-search` working after tweaking `include` & `includeexpr` expression for Python

Tags: vim

I'm trying *include-search* based settings in my vim configuration. Which is causing `[i`, `[i`, `[d`, `]d`, etc. cmds not working as expected. In addition when `:checkpath!` is run to look at included files, its not working as expected either.
Could you please help me let me know what am i doing wrong & what can i do to fix this.

1. My project root looks like below. I've intentionally not listing entries of `venv` dir, just to keep the entry list small.

   ```
   \> tree -I "build|dist|*egg*|__pycache__" -L 2
   .
   ├── MANIFEST.in
   ├── README.md
   ├── acs_datamodels-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
   ├── ai_core-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
   ├── datamodels
   │   ├── __init__.py
   │   ├── fabric.py
   │   ├── literals.py
   │   └── precompute.py
   ├── encrypt.log
   ├── setup.py
   ├── tests
   │   ├── __init__.py
   │   ├── data
   │   ├── test_fabric.py
   │   └── test_precompute.py
   └── venv
       ├── bin
       ├── include
       ├── lib
       ├── lib64 -> lib
       └── pyvenv.cfg
   ```
2. my `:set path?` looks like

   ```
   path=datamodels,venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/*/**2
   ```
3. my `:set include?` looks like

   ```
   ^\s*\(from\|import\)\s*\zs\(\S\+\|\S\+\s*import\{1}\s*\S\+\)\ze\($\|\s*as\|,\)
   ```
4. my `:set includeexpr?` looks like

   ```
   includeexpr=PyInclude(v:fname)
   ```
5. contents of `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim` is as below

   ```
   set shiftwidth=4 tabstop=4 softtabstop=4 expandtab autoindent smartindent
   setlocal wildignore=*.pyc,bin,*egg*,__pycache__/*,build,dist
   setlocal include=^\\s*\\(from\\\|import\\)\\s*\\zs\\(\\S\\+\\\|\\S\\+\\s*import\\{1}\\s*\\S\\+\\)\\ze\\($\\\|\\s*as\\\|,\\)

   function! PyInclude(fname)
       echom "fname: " a:fname
       let parts = split(a:fname, ' import ')
       echom "parts: " parts
       let l = parts[0]    " (1) logging (2) ai_core.commons (3) datamodels.literals
       if len(parts) > 1
           let r = parts[1]    " (1) datamodels (2) datetime 
           let joined = join([l, r], '.')  " datetime.datetime, ai_core.commons.decode_token
           let fp = substitute(joined, '\.', '/', 'g') . '.py' " datetime/datetime, ai_core/commons/decode_token
           let found = glob(fp, 1)
           echom "parts > 1" found
           if len(found)
               return found
           endif
       endif
       let kp = substitute(l, '\.', '/', 'g') . '.py'
       echom "parts < 1" kp
       return kp    " ai_core/commons.py, datamodels/literals.py
   endfunction

   setlocal includeexpr=PyInclude(v:fname)
   ```
6. Output of `:checkpath!` is as below. Please note the output also contains some debug msg i'd added. If you see `from typing import Dict` and `import logging` has been identified from `venv` dir, but other libraries: `from ai_core.commons import decode_token` which i've installed from wheel file are  not recognized, even though they're are there in `venv` dir. Also, the other module from current file's relative path `import datamodels.literals` is not recognized.

   ```
   fname:  typing import Dict
   parts:  ['typing', 'Dict']
   parts > 1
   parts < 1 typing.py
   venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/typing.py

   fname:  ai_core.commons import decode_token
   parts:  ['ai_core.commons', 'decode_token']
   parts > 1
   parts < 1 ai_core/commons.py
   ai_core.commons import decode_token  NOT FOUND

   fname:  logging
   parts:  ['logging']
   parts < 1 logging.py
   venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/logging.py

   fname:  datamodels.literals
   parts:  ['datamodels.literals']
   parts < 1 datamodels/literals.py
   datamodels.literals  NOT FOUND
   ```

I've learnt these from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gs1VDYnS-Ac&t=1s) video, thanks a ton to [Leeren](https://twitter.com/leeren) for introducing these and many more to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&path` is a whitelist of directories in which to search for files. Basically, you can think of include search as appending the filename to every directory listed in `&path` and seeing if that path leads to something (it doesn't really work like that but that's a good enough mental model for the problem at hand).

For example, if your filename is `quux` and your `&path` is `foo,bar,baz`, then Vim is going to search for the following files:

```
foo/quux
bar/quux
baz/quux
```

Here, the filename is `datamodels/literals.py` and your `&path` is `datamodels,venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/*/**2` so Vim is going to search for:

```
datamodels/datamodels/literals.py
venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/*/**/datamodels/literals.py
venv/...
```

and fail for *rather obvious* reasons.

There are two ways to go around that:

- Prepend your `&path` with `.,,`, which tells Vim to search for files in the directory of the current file and in the working directory. Your `&path` would look like this:

  ```
  .,,datamodels,venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/*/**2
  ```

  which should let Vim find `datamodels/literals.py` easily:

  ```
  datamodels/literals.py    <-- BINGO!
  datamodels/datamodels/literals.py
  venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/*/**/datamodels/literals.py
  venv/...
  ```
- Make your `&includeexpr` return `literals.py`, which can be found with your current `&path`, instead of `datamodels/literals.py`:

  ```
  datamodels/literals.py    <-- BINGO!
  venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/*/**/literals.py
  venv/...
  ```

IMO, you should do both.

Comment: As for the `ai_core/commons.py` issue, is there actually a `commons.py` file at the expected location?

Comment: hi, thanks for the detailed explanation, i will surely look at it. As far as ```ai_core/commons.py```, it does present under ```venv/lib/python3/site-packages/``` dir.

Answer (score 0):

Did `:set path=.,,venv/lib/python3/site-packages/**2` did the magic. The correction is `**2` to represent subdirs with 2 level deep instead of `*/**2` from my original post.
Yes as [@romail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546861/romainl) pointed, i did try appending each filename from `includeexpr` to the dir list in `path`. Thank you.